# Using Vertex Buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I using many polygons (in RAM), this very slowly. Say, please: how using a vertex buffer in OpenGL? (functions etc.) 
(programing language - C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read a tutorial about this like this one:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/#The_VAO

I can give you this code snippet:

```
float vertices[] = {
 1, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 1, 0, 1,
 0, 0, 1, 1,
 };

GLuint vertexnumber = 3; //Amount of vertices in your array

int VertexStrideSize = 4*sizeof(float); //How much values you give for one vertex

// Create the vertex buffer object
GLuint buf;
glGenBuffers( 1, &buf );    //Create the buffer
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf ); //Binding the buffer
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexStrideSize*vertexnumber, vertices,  GL_STATIC_DRAW ); //Fill the buffer

// For your vertex shader
GLuint posLoc = glGetAttribLocation(shadername, "aPosition"); //In your shader you can use the variable aPosition now as a input with "in vec4 aPosition"
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VertexStrideSize,  0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
```

Comment: Error: glGenBuffers is not defined. :( (Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев [try this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=glGenBuffers+is+not+defined).